# How to implement proper innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: mysql

In My Database 
InnoDB_buffer_pool_size=4294967296
innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests=816834793

Please Give reply for i am satisfy with this issue?.

Comment: Innodb_buffer_pool_reads=16015300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than 4GB of RAM set `innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 70% of *available* RAM.

The setting is done in the `[mysqld]` section of the `my.cnf` file.  And you must restart mysqld to get it to take effect.

[*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory)